# Google Trusty TEE implementation

Tags: java, android, android-studio, trusted-execution-environment

I am working on a mobile vault app in Android, I'm new to this field (TEE), and I have searched a lot about how to implement Trusty TEE but did not find any tutorial.

1. How can I implement Google Trusty TEE in an android app, how do I enable it? Any links or tutorials?
2. If not Google Trusty TEE, which TEE can I use?

Comment: You don't implement TEE, you use it as [part of Android OS on supported hardware](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#HardwareSecurityModule) Not clear if you've seen: [Android Developers - Security with Data](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data)